# How to get latest bitcoin price in MySQL using Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the latest bitcoin price and save it in my database. I keep getting the error `NameError: name 'price_usd' is not defined` when I execute my python script:

**getdata.py**

```
import requests
import urllib
import json
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'dbuser',passwd = 'dbpass',db = 'bitcoinprice')
cursor = con.cursor()
url = 'example.com'
urllib.urlopen(url).read()
response = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print(response)
json_obj = str(response)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bitcoinprice (list_price_usd) VALUES (%s)", (price_usd))
con.commit()
con.close()

print (json_obj)
```

**Returned JSON from API**

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "11117.3", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "9729550000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "187080534738", 
        "available_supply": "16827875.0", 
        "total_supply": "16827875.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.09", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-0.9", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-4.32", 
        "last_updated": "1516991668"
    }
]
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `bitcoinprice` (
  `list_id` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_name` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_symbol` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_rank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_price_usd` decimal(7,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_price_btc` decimal(9,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_24h_volume_usd` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_market_cap_usd` decimal(12,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_available_supply` decimal(12,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_total_supply` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_max_supply` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_percent_change_1h` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_percent_change_24h` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_percent_change_7d` decimal(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_last_updated` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please provide the schema for the database table= bitcoinprice.

Comment: Well, you haven't defined price_usd anywhere in your code. It might begin the response but you've not attempted to parse that.

Comment: `print(json_obj['price_usd'])` ?

Comment: Where do you define price_usd in your program? I don't see anything but an entry in your json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "returned json from api" is correct:

Replace

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bitcoinprice (list_price_usd) VALUES (%s)", (price_usd))
```

With

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bitcoinprice (list_price_usd) VALUES (%s)",
    (json.loads(json_obj)[0]['price_usd']))
```

For whatever reason, you seem to have imported the json module (the solution to your problem) without actually using it.

json.loads converts a json string into a python object, which in your case is a list containing one value, a dict with the data you want. `[0]` gets the dictionary from the list, and `['price_usd']` gets the value you were expecting to be stored in a variable named price_usd from the dict.